# How to copy a private folder with content to public directory in android q and higher?

Tags: android, mediastore, deprecation-warning, android-api-levels

I have a private folder that contains sub folders with images and videos,
I need to copy that folder to Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES for public

val fodler = getExternalFilesDir("Folder")  //  contains sub folders with images and videos

val DESTINATION = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() +
File.separator + Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES

copyFileOrDirectory(fodler.absolutePath, DESTINATION)

```
private fun copyFileOrDirectory(srcDir: String, dstDir: String) {
    try {
        val src: File = File(srcDir)
        val dst: File = File(dstDir, src.name)
        if (src.isDirectory) {
            val files = src.list()
            val filesLength = files.size
            for (i in 0 until filesLength) {
                val src1 = File(src, files[i]).path
                val dst1 = dst.path
                copyFileOrDirectory(src1, dst1)
            }
        } else {
            copyFile(src, dst)
        }
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
}

private fun copyFile(sourceFile: File, destFile: File) {
    if (!destFile.getParentFile().exists()) destFile.getParentFile().mkdirs()
    if (!destFile.exists()) {
        destFile.createNewFile()
    }
    var source: FileChannel? = null
    var destination: FileChannel? = null
    try {
        source = FileInputStream(sourceFile).getChannel()
        destination = FileOutputStream(destFile).getChannel()
        destination.transferFrom(source, 0, source.size())
    } finally {
        if (source != null) {
            source.close()
        }
        if (destination != null) {
            destination.close()
        }
    }
}
```

now I get the file "folder" (with all its content) in "Pictures" directory, visible to everyone and public,
exactly what I need.

This solution works for api levels 23-29 (android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" for api level 29 in menifest)
but it doesn't work in api level 30 because getExternalStorageDirectory() is deprecated and android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" in menifest doesn't work for api level 30

what will be the solution for api level 30 ?

Comment: "android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" in menifest doesn't work for api level 30" -- it does if your `targetSdkVersion` is below 30. The Play Store will require 30 later this year, though. "what will be the solution for api level 30 ?" -- either use `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE` and let the user choose where the content should be copied, or use `MediaStore`.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thanks for the quick answer, I have tried to use  both ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE and MediaStore but from some reason I always get the same Exception : java.io.IOException: No such file or directory. I would be very grateful if you could give a working code example

Comment: "I always get the same Exception" -- perhaps ask separate Stack Overflow questions for each, providing a [mcve] and including the complete stack trace of the exception. "I would be very grateful if you could give a working code example" -- sorry, but I do not have code samples for these specific scenarios. I have [this 14 blog post series](https://commonsware.com/blog/2019/10/19/scoped-storage-stories-saf-basics.html) on the general topics, though.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thanks for directing me to use ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE, now it works fine

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to use kotlin to show you an example but, if your problem is what in sdk < 29 you can't use `getExternalStorageDirectory()` is deprecated maybe you should use MediaStore to save files (images):

```
private void saveImage(Bitmap bitmap) {
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 29) {
        ContentValues values = contentValues(); //define your content values to save data
        values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.RELATIVE_PATH, "Pictures/" + "Example Folder"); //here your path 
        values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.IS_PENDING, true);
        Uri uri = this.getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values); //this to insert data 
        if (uri != null) {
            try {
                saveImageToStream(bitmap, this.getContentResolver().openOutputStream(uri)); //so save the image file
                values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.IS_PENDING, false);
                Toast.makeText(this, "It works!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    } else { //and if sdk < 29 
        File directory = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + '/' + getString(R.string.app_name));
        if (!directory.exists()) {
            directory.mkdirs();
        }
        String fileName = "file" + ".jpg";
        File file = new File(directory, fileName);
        try {
            saveImageToStream(bitmap, new FileOutputStream(file));
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA, file.getAbsolutePath());
            this.getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}

private ContentValues contentValues() { //here we do the some values to save in sdk>=29
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME, "fileImage" + ".jpg");
    values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.MIME_TYPE, "image/*");
    values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_ADDED, System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
        values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_TAKEN, System.currentTimeMillis());
    }
    return values;
}

private void saveImageToStream(Bitmap bitmap, OutputStream outputStream) { //and this to give a format 
if (outputStream != null) {
    try {
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, outputStream);
        outputStream.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For api 30 devices you can just copy your folder to the Pictures directory as always.

Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES) works so use it.

But.. the files need to be pictures.

For api 29 request legacy external storage in application tag of manifest file to copy to public  Pictures directory.